# create a python sequence of 1-D array_like in C++

Tags: c++, python-3.x, embedding

I'm trying to embed Python in my C++ code.

Now what I'm trying to do is use the function [scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp.html) that takes as input a "sequence of 1-D array_like".

the thing is that in Python one would call the function in this simple way:

```
from scipy import stats

# two example np-arrays
samp1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
samp2 = np.array([0,5,6,7,3,9,2,7,1,7])
ander_out1, ander_out2, ander_out3 = stats.anderson_ksamp([samp1, samp2])
print("Anderson statistic: %s, critical values: %s, significance level: %s"% (ander_out1, ander_out2, ander_out3))
```

In C++ instead I call this function in this way:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

std::vector<int> sample1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
std::vector<int> sample2 = {0,5,6,7,3,9,2,7,1,7};

Py_Initialize();

import_array();

npy_intp dim1[] = {(npy_intp)sample1.size()};
PyObject* np_array1 = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dim1, NPY_INT, &sample1[0]);
npy_intp dim2[] = {(npy_intp)sample2.size()};
PyObject* np_array2 = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dim2, NPY_INT, &sample2[0]);


pModule2 = PyImport_ImportModule("scipy.stats");
if (pModule2 != NULL) {

    pValue3 = PyObject_CallMethod(pModule2, "anderson_ksamp", "O", /*HERE GOES THE 1-D SEQUENCE*/);
    if (pValue3 != NULL) {
        Py_ssize_t pValue3Size = PyTuple_Size(pValue3); // size of the tuple
        printf("Anderson tuple: (");
        for (Py_ssize_t j = 0; j < pValue3Size; j++) {
            pElem3 = PyTuple_GetItem(pValue3, j); // getting item j of tuple
            printf("%f", PyFloat_AsDouble(pElem3)); // printing item j
            if (j!=pValue3Size-1) {
                printf(", ");
            }
        }
        printf(")\n");
    } else {
        printf("Call to anderson_ksamp failed.\n");
        PyErr_Print();
    }
}
```

What I miss is how to "merge" the two vectors `sample1` and `sample2` in order to make a Python object that resembles the Python statement `[samp1, samp2]`.

I tried to create a 2-D vector in C++

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> sample3 = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}, {0,5,6,7,3,9,2,7,1,7}};
```

and then use

```
npy_intp dim3[] = {10, 2};
PyObject* both_np_arrays = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dim3, NPY_INT, &sample3);
```

in order to create the object I need. But the object I get is something like this:

```
array([[ 8003984,        1],
       [ 8004032,        1],
       [ 8004032,        1],
       [50571184,        1],
       [50411920,        1],
       [       0,        0],
       [       0,        0],
       [       0,        0],
       [       0,        0],
       [       0,        0]], dtype=int32)
```

That is definitely not what I want.

I've also tried to do it this way:

```
int sample3[10][2] = {{1,0}, {2,5}, {3,6}, {4,7}, {5,3}, {6,9}, {7,2}, {8,7}, {9,1}, {0,7}};
npy_intp dim3[] = {10, 2};
PyObject* both_np_arrays = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dim3, NPY_INT, &sample3);
```

but the result is this:

```
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6],
       [4, 7],
       [5, 3],
       [6, 9],
       [7, 2],
       [8, 7],
       [9, 1],
       [0, 7]], dtype=int32)
```

so, again, not what I need.

I think that to use the function properly I'd need to obtain something like this:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0],
       [0, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9, 2, 7, 1, 7]], dtype=int32)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Try `int sample3[2][10] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0},{0, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9, 2, 7, 1, 7}};` and then  `npy_intp dim3[] = {2,10};` then
`PyObject* both_np_arrays = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dim3, NPY_INT, &sample3);`

Comment: It gives me an array in the shape I need it, thank you! But is there a way I can create an array like that from the two vectors `sample1` and `sample2`? Something like: `int sample3[2][10] = {&sample1[0], &sample2[0]};
` (of course this doesn't compile)